# How to forward specific event to overlapped DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

[image]

I have two completely overlapped `divs`; The top layer has a scroll behavior because it has overflowing content, and I want to keep the scrolling behavior.

The underlying layer has different section with different click handler; boxes (X, Y, Z) in the picture.

**How do I have a click handler for the underlying layer while keeping the scrolling on the top layer?**

> I have tried CSS `pointer-events: none;` but it forwards all events,
> which cause the scrolling on the top layer to be disabled.
>
> I have tried to manually  `dispatchEvent` using javascript, but the
> event sourcing doesn't work as normal.

Here is the DOM structure

```html
 <div>
    <div
      ref="layer2"
      class="
        layer2
        h-96
        cursor-pointer
        text-2xl text-center
        flex
        space-x-4
        items-center
        justify-center
        bg-green-400
      "
      style="width: 600px"
      @click="handleLayer2"
    >
      <div
        @click="handleSection('x')"
        class="w-[200px] h-[8rem] bg-red-600 shadow-lg rounded h-24"
      >
        X
      </div>
      <div
        @click="handleSection('y')"
        class="w-[200px] h-[8rem] bg-red-600 shadow-lg rounded h-24"
      >
        Y
      </div>
      <div
        @click="handleSection('z')"
        class="w-[200px] h-[8rem] bg-red-600 shadow-lg rounded h-24"
      >
        Z
      </div>
    </div>

    <div
      class="
        layer1
        absolute
        top-0
        left-0
        bg-pink-500
        h-96
        text-xl
        whitespace-nowrap
        text-center
        opacity-70
        overflow-scroll
        pt-64
      "
      style="width: 600px"
      @click="handleLayer1"
    >
      really long content ...
    </div>
```

Here is a complete reproduction https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-dtxxqa?file=src/App.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make my explanation easier I'll need to give each of the divs names. Let's call the absolutely positioned div `topDiv`, and the divs underneath `downDivs`.

You're also going to need a click handler on `topDiv` itself. That handler is what we will use to "forward" the event to the `downDivs`.

In your `topDiv` click handler, you'd do something like this:

```js
// first hide the `topDiv`
event.target.hidden = true;

// Get the element underneath that also falls under the click location
let downDiv = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);

// Unhide the topDiv
event.target.hidden = false;

// We still need to confirm that the element gotten is actually a downDiv
if (!downDiv.classList.includes('down-div'))
    return;

// Now we can dispatch a duplicate click event on the downDiv
downDiv.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
    bubbles: true,
    pageX: event.pageX,
    pageY: event.pageY,
    clientX: event.clientX,
    clientY: event.clientY,
}));

// Now you can handle the clicks on the downDiv anyway you like :)
```

You can read this article to learn more about [event dispatching](https://javascript.info/dispatch-events)

Comment: Thank you! I guessed dispatchEvent should work